# Check if the python string contains specific characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a program that prompts user for input and  should print True only if every character in string entered by the user is either a digit ('0' - '9') or one of the first six letters in the alphabet ('A' - 'F'). Otherwise the program should print False.

I can't use regex for this question as it is not taught yet, i wanted to use basic boolean operations . This is the code I have so far, but it also outputs ABCH as true because of Or's. I am stuck

```py
string = input("Please enter your string: ")

output = string.isdigit() or ('A' in string or 'B' or string or 'C' in string or 'D' in string or 'E' in string or 'F' in string)

print(output)
```

Also i am not sure if my program should treat lowercase letters and uppercase letters as different, also does string here means one word or a sentence?

Comment: `string` is the entire object. You should loop over each element in string like `for char in string:` and then perform your logic.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid  i used this , still returns true on WEDA
string = input("Please enter your string: ")

for char in string: 
    if char == ("A" or "B" or "C" or "D" or "E" or "F"):
        alphabet_output = "True"
    else: 
        alphabet_output = "False"
        
    
output = string.isdigit() or alphabet_output
print(output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `str.lower` method to make each element lowercase since it sounds like case is not important for your problem.

```py
string = input("Please enter your string: ")
output = True # default value

for char in string: # Char will be an individual character in string
    if (not char.lower() in "abcdef") and (not char.isdigit()):
        # if the lowercase char is not in "abcdef" or is not a digit:
        output = False
        break; # Exits the for loop

print(output)
```

`output` will only be changed to `False` if the string fails any of your tests. Otherwise, it will be `True`.

Comment: You could also use the built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to further simplify: `output = all(c.isdigit() or c.lower() in 'abcdef' for c in s)`

Comment: @syntaxVoid: this code fails for test case ABCDD, it should return true but it returns false

Comment: Sorry, it is fixed now. I changed the `or` to `and` in the if statement.